# argparse says "error: argument is required" even though script is called with argument

Tags: python, argparse

I'm running into trouble when trying to load images from this Python script.
It's running fine in Windows 10. I'm not sure why it's not working in my Windows 7 system.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
            help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

In CMD I run,

```
showimage.py --image syiling.png
```

then it returns

```
showimage.py: error: argument is required
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the .py file association is wrong. In the Control Panel -> Default Progams -> Set Associations list, make sure .py files are associated with the "Python File" type from the Python Software Foundation. If so, open an administrator command prompt and check `ftype Python.File`. It should be something like `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*`. The `"%L"` (or `"%1"`) parameter is the script path. The `%*` parameter is for the command-line arguments.

Comment: nonsense. the script is clearly executed as python. the issue is how to use `argparse`.

Comment: Are you copy+pasting in your execution command or typing it in?  If you're doing a copy+paste, its possible some non-printable character is being included, or maybe your `--` characters are the wrong `-` character.
 Do you get the same error if you use `-i` instead of `--image`?